# Как очистить кэш проекта в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Как очистить кэш проекта в Intellij IDEA ?

Открыл программу Intellij и она забрала у диска 300 мегабайт, хотя она открыла всё тот же проект который я вел и при этом сам никакие проекты не открывал, вот хочу узнать как очистить кэш.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Я так сделал](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где физически [они лежат описано тут](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html?_ga=2.262977288.563742711.1605244177-850088091.1605244177#config-directory)

там пишут примерно так :*По умолчанию IntelliJ IDEA хранит пользовательские файлы (конфигурацию, кеши, плагины, журналы и т. Д.) в домашнем каталоге пользователя.*